# SKAction followPath, creating the path

Tags: ios, path-finding, sprite-kit, cgpath, skaction

I am using a simple A* Pathfinding algorithm to create a path between two points (the green and red circles below), each square is an SKSpriteNode (with a `CGPoint` [x,y] position). I want to animate another `SKSpriteNode` along a smooth path that passes through each point.

My thinking was that I could use the `SKAction` `-followPath:duration:` to do this but I am having trouble working out how to create/specify the `CGPath`. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple CGPath like this

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100);
```

Depending on what you want to achieve you can add different elements to your path like arcs, curves, rects...
You can find more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211).

Comment: Thank you, can I ask, will the path be smooth or is it just linear lines between the [x,y] coords?

Comment: Sure thing just use CGContextAddCurveToPoint instead of CGPathAddLineToPoint. There is a nice [section on paths in Quartz 2D programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211).

Comment: Much appreciated, ill have a look right now and mark you answer later. Many thanks again.

Comment: You can't just swap in the curve, if you start using CGContextAddCurveToPoint then the path is invalid as you need to specify a context not a path.

Comment: My bad, you should use CGPathAddCurveToPoint, which replaces CGContextAddCurveToPoint

Comment: Cool thank you, one final question, given that I have a set of [x,y]  points that I wish the curve to follow is there a simple way of defining the control points. If not its going to difficult to work out where the control points need to be to get the curve to flow through my points.

Comment: What I was hoping for was something like a Catmull-Rom curve where the curve flows through the points specified.